# Arquillian - Single deployment for all tests

Tags: java, testing, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian framework to execute tests in managed container(Wildfly).

I created deployable war archive with all classes inside in deployment method.

What I would like to know is if there is possibility to run all test cases against single deployment.
So I would not have to include Deployment method in each test class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not part of the core functionality of Arquillian, but there's a popular Suite Extension which does exactly what you are looking for. Check their GitHub repo for more details https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide https://rpestano.wordpress.com/category/arquillian/#multiple_deploy
You create a single test class with one method annotated as @Deployment and multiple @Test methods that calls the real tests. Real tests are written in beans that are injected into the single test class